# Calling python script from another directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script Base.py , having path say username/packageName/Base.py

Another python script Application.py, having path username/packageName/bin/Application.py

How can i call the method of Application.py from Base.py, since both being in different folder.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "call the method of Application.py from Base.py"? Suggest you add some sample code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the `bin` directory, make an empty file called `__init__.py` (two underscores on each side, for a total of *4* underscores). After doing that, Python will treat `bin` as a Python module, and then you can do:

```
from bin import Application
# e.g.
Application.yourApplicationFunction(params)
```

In your `base.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends by what you mean with 'call'.

If you mean importing a module, by default only the current directory and the Python library path are used (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path); anyway, you can use the "imp" (https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html):

```
import imp

foo = imp.load_source('module.name', 'username/packageName/Base.py')
foo.MyClass()
```

On the other side, if you meaning 'run' the script you could use following syscall implementations:

- exec (): run an executable in the context of the caller process, effectively destroying the caller
- fork (): creates a new child process (exact duplicate of the parent that starts at the current point)
- system (): like exec but new process is a kind of fork, parent wait and re-gain control at the end

Comment: I tried subprocess.call (giving the path of base.py).. But its showing me permission denied

Comment: Has your caller script the proper permissions on the filesystem? Is the called script executable ('chmod +x $file')?

Comment: Is this question answered?